# euclidian spaces, subspaces , conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra

In euclidian space $X$ there are given linear subspaces $U, V\subset X$ such that $U\bot V$.  Then:
a. $\dim X \ge \dim U + \dim V$
b. there are exists vectors $u\in U, v\in V$ such that $||u||=||v||=1$ and $\langle u,v\rangle = 0 $
c. there are exists vectors $u\in U, v\in V$ such that $||u||=||v||=1$ and $\langle u,v\rangle = 1$

a. it is true, because $\dim U + \dim V= \dim(U+V) + \dim(U\cap V)$.
 Because of the fact that $U\bot V$ $\dim (U\cap V)=0$.  So, $\dim U+\dim V = \dim(U+V) \le \dim X$.  Why ? Because of the fact that $x\in U+V\Rightarrow x\in X$,
   $x=u+v$.   $u$ and $v$ may be expressed in base of $X$, so $x$ may be expressed in base of $X$.

b. It is obvious that $\langle u, v\rangle =0$. It is possible also that we have normalize $u$, and $v$. So b. is true.

c. it is not possible, because we have that $\forall u\in U\forall v\in V \langle u, v\rangle = 0$
Am I ok ?

Comment: Seems good. ${}$

Comment: I mean, assuming $U,V \neq \{0\}$. Otherwise b and c are false. If they're not, you're good to go.

Comment: Ok, Yes. If $U=\{0\}$ or $V=\{0\}$ (or $U=V=\{0\}$)  then b. and c. are false. You are right.